# Add noise_model when using 'ibmq_qasm_simulator' backend and provider.runtime.run() function

Tags: simulation, noise, error-mitigation, qiskit-runtime

I am trying to test some qiskit code that employs readout-error mitigation using the `ibmq_qasm_simulator` backend and Qiskit Runtime. I am getting the backend as follows:

```
IBMQ.load_account() 
provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub=...)
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_qasm_simulator')
```

I can then change the backend's noise model like so:

```
#noise model based on real machine
device_backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_belem')
noise_model = noise.NoiseModel.from_backend(device_backend)
backend.options.update_options(noise_model=noise_model)
```

And I can see that the noise_model has changed by printing out `backend.options`.

The problem that I'm running into is that changes to the backend options don't get picked up by the function `provider.runtime.run` because it only takes the backend's **name** and not it's ***properties***. See below:

```
program_inputs = {
    'circuits': qc,
    'optimization_level': 3,
    'measurement_error_mitigation': True,
    'memory': True,
    'shots': 50,
    }
options = {'backend_name': 'ibmq_qasm_simulator'}
job = provider.runtime.run(program_id="circuit-runner",
                               options=options,
                               inputs=program_inputs
                              )
```

where qc is just a 3-qubit quantum circuit defined earlier.

All of the explicit examples that I can find for using noise models in qiskit use the Aer simulator. I've tried seeing if I could add a noise model through `providers.runtime.run`'s options or inputs, but that doesn't seem to be possible. I also thought that maybe I could create a new backend that's a copy of the `ibmq_qasm_simulator` backend but where I added the noise model and changed the backend's name, but I haven't been able to figure out how to change the name of an `IBMQBackend` instance.

I believe that what I'm trying to do is possible based on the description of the `ibmq_qasm_simulator` [here](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/lab/docs/iql/manage/simulator/):

*"A general-purpose simulator for simulating quantum circuits both ideally and subject to noise modeling. The simulation method is automatically selected based on the input circuits and parameters."*

Thank you so much for your help!!!

P.S. This is my first quantum-computing project, so please be gentle... :)