# Is it possible to use fake backends to run Qiskit Runtime primitives?

Tags: qiskit, simulation, noise, qiskit-runtime

I have the following code to run an [`Estimator`](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/services/programs/primitives?program=estimator) primitive by using Qiskit Runtime. It computes the expectation value $\langle O \rangle = \langle \psi | O | \psi \rangle$ (in this example $\langle 0 | Z | 0 \rangle = 1$ with zero variance):

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService, Options, Session, Estimator


# prepare the state |Ψ>
qc = QuantumCircuit(1)

# define the operator/observable O
O = SparsePauliOp(['Z'])

service = QiskitRuntimeService()
backend = 'ibmq_qasm_simulator'
options = Options(resilience_level=0)

with Session(service=service, backend=backend) as session:
    estimator = Estimator(session=session, options=options)
    job = estimator.run(circuits=[qc], observables=[O])

print(job.result().values)
```

I know that Qiskit Runtime primitives can run on real IBM quantum devices but what I'm wondering whether is possible run them by using fake backends (or, more in general, custom noise models). For example, how can I run the code above on the `FakeManila` backend or passing a `NoiseModel` instance? Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

##### Using primitives with fake backends

You can use `BackendEstimator` to work with fake backends. As [primitives](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/primitives.html) implementation, [`BackendEstimator`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.primitives.BackendEstimator.html) and [`BackendSampler`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.primitives.BackendSampler.html) are designed to be generic that can work with almost any backend.

```
from qiskit.primitives import BackendEstimator

estimator = BackendEstimator(backend = FakeNairobi())

job = estimator.run(qc, O)
result = job.result()
print(result.values)
```

Note that, if you are dealing with a provider that has native primitive implementations, like Qiskit Runtime or [Qiskit Aer](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/aer_primitives.html), you should use that native implementation. Most probably, it will be much more efficient.

---

##### Using primitives with Qiskit runtime noisy simulators

If what you want is to use primitives with Qiskit runtime noisy simulators, you can easily do that by creating the `NoiseModel` and passing it to the estimator options as follows:

```
from qiskit_aer.noise import NoiseModel

noisy_backend = service.get_backend('ibm_nairobi')
backend_noise_model = NoiseModel.from_backend(noisy_backend)

simulator = service.get_backend('ibmq_qasm_simulator')

options = Options()
options.resilience_level = 0
options.optimization_level = 0
options.simulator = {
    "noise_model": backend_noise_model
}

with Session(service=service, backend=simulator) as session:
    estimator = Estimator(session=session, options=options)
    job = estimator.run(circuits=qc, observables=O)
    print(job.result().values)
```

Comment: Ok thank you! It seems that the Qiskit Runtime provider does not include fake backends right?

Comment: That's correct. However, that does not mean you can't load a custom `NoiseModel` into runtime simulators. I updated my answer to cover this point.

Comment: That looks fine, thank you. However, I tried to run the simulation loading the custom noise model but I still get perfect result with variance 0. I think this is an already encountered issue, previously mentioned [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/25609/add-noise-model-when-using-ibmq-qasm-simulator-backend-and-provider-runtime-ru).

Comment: Code works with me without issue. Try to increase the depth of your circuit such that the noise affects the result. e.g., `qc = random_circuit(1, 10, 1, seed=1)`

Comment: To properly test that code, you have to pick a circuit which, in case of a perfect simulation with no noise, returns a completely deterministic result (like the one I used in my question) and check that, loading the noise model, you get a little deviation from the expected final result (at non-zero variance).
If you use a `random_circuit` the result will be non-deterministic because of its quantum nature and having a non-zero variance does not imply that the simulation has correctly loaded the passed noise model.

Comment: Noise model should be passed to estimator options instead of passing it to the simulator. I updated my answer to correct the code snippet.